# MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET problem ( wrong target version )

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos

when i try to compile my flutter program i got this :

```
/* com.apple.ibtool.errors */
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Runner/Base.lproj/MainMenu.xib: error: Compilation failed. Unable to write to path: /Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/build/macos/Build/Products/Debug/AvekIA.app/Contents/Resources/Base.lproj/MainMenu.nib
    Underlying Errors:
        Description: The file “MainMenu.nib” couldn’t be saved in the folder “Base.lproj”.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. Is a directory
            Failure Reason: Is a directory
        Description: “MainMenu.nib” couldn’t be removed because you don’t have permission to access it.
        Failure Reason: You don’t have permission.
        Recovery Suggestion: To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info.
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: The operation couldn’t be completed. Permission denied
            Failure Reason: Permission denied
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'url_launcher_macos' from project 'Pods')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'catcher' from project 'Pods')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'package_info_plus_macos' from project 'Pods')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'path_provider_macos' from project 'Pods')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'device_info_plus_macos' from project 'Pods')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'Pods-Runner' from project 'Pods')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Runner.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'Flutter Assemble' from project 'Runner')
warning: Run script build phase 'Run Script' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
/Users/maxime/avekia/flutter_ssi_app/avekia/macos/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The macOS deployment target 'MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 10.11, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 10.13 to 13.0.99. (in target 'FlutterMacOS' from project 'Pods')
** BUILD FAILED **

Exception: Build process failed
```

I've tried to change the

```
platform :osx, '10.11'
```

to 10.13 inside macos/podfile but it didn't help.
I also tried to change

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_macos_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

to

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_macos_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.13'
    end
  end
end
```

with this some errors disappear ( with 'in target 'path_provider_macos' from project 'Pods'') but i kept others.

Thanks for the help